# Linq Error Cannot Operate on Variables of Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Apparently I've gone silly on Wednesday morning. I have linq error that I should know the answer. Sorry for the stupid question.

```
var results1 = (from p in db1.a_PCRs
            join je in db1.a_Job_Extensions on p.PCR equals je.PCR
            join j in db1.Jobs on je.Job equals j.Job1
            join d in db1.Deliveries on j.Job1 equals d.Job
            where j.Status == "Active"
            where j.Job1.StartsWith("A")
            where p.PCR == "2552"
            where d.Shipped_Quantity > 0
            orderby d.Shipped_Date descending
            select new
            {
                p.PCR,
                d.Shipped_Date
            }).FirstOrDefault();

if (results1 != null)
{
    foreach (var result1 in results1)
    {
        lastDeliveryDate = result1.Shipped_Date;
    }

}else
{
    lastDeliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1980");
}
```

The error is on the foreach loop on the "results1" item.

```
Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '<anonymous type: string PCR, DateTime? Shipped_Date>' because '<anonymous type: string PCR, DateTime? Shipped_Date>' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

Can anyone push me in the right direction here?

Comment: Is this really linq-to-sql?

Comment: Yes it is. Its accessing four different tables on a sql server database so that's linq to sql based on what Microsoft says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are grabbing the first item in your query when you call .FirstOrDefault(). You can't iterate that with a foreach, it's a single item.

Based on your logic, your query is already grabbing the correct item ordered by 'Shipped_Date'.  I think you want to just drop the foreach -

```
if (results1 != null)
{
    lastDeliveryDate = results1.Shipped_Date;
}
else
{
    lastDeliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1980");
}
```

Comment: Jonesopolis you are dead on! Thank you!